# Create Managed Metadata Column in SharePoint Hosted Add in

Tags: managed-metadata, sharepoint-hosted-app, xml, schema, list-column

I am creating a SharePoint Hosed Add-In and my requirement is, add a managed metadata list column through list schema.xml.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could add list columns by list schema, then map the list column to the Managed Metadata term group.

More references:

SharePoint: Create List With Lookup, Choice, Date And Person Fields (Schema).

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/sharepoint-create-list-with-lookup-choice-date-and-person/

Sharepoint 2013: Programmatically creating Managed Metadata column & mapping it with termset.

http://sharepointpals.com/post/Sharepoint-2013-Programmatically-creating-Managed-Metadata-column-mapping-it-with-termset

Create Managed Metadata column (TaxonomyFieldType) in Visual Studio.

https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/create-managed-metadata-column-taxonomyfieldtype-in-visual-studio/